# Runescape : I do not earn exp

Tags: runescape

I have a big problem, my combat level is 57 and I just got level 25 att,def and str. And the problem is that i dont get anymore exp by killing creatures, or anything. Pls help me out!

Comment: I haven't played Runescape for years, and this isn't a proper question, but let's diagnose this. Each point of damage you do contributes 1 xp to your health experience and 4 xp to attack or defense or strength depending on the style you're using. I don't know how styles have been affected by the recent combat rework, so look at your health skill. How much experience do you have there now? How much experience do you have after killing one enemy? Did it go up?

Comment: Yes, My health went up, and the attack skill too, but defense and strenght aren't going up...

Comment: Yup, this is because you are using an accurate style. Try changing your attack type.

Comment: Yeah maybe, i always use the battleaxes... I'll try But thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the Evolution of Combat update, there is a separate interface for choosing what skill to gain combat experience in. When you are in game, click on the combat interface panel by clicking on the crossed swords icon.

[image]

If you click the circular button labeled "XP", there will be an interface that lets you choose what skill(s) to gain experience for melee combat, ranged combat, and magic combat (note that you always gain constitution experience regardless of your choice).

[image]

Note that choosing "Attack, Strength & Defence" does not increase the experience you gain, it just splits the experience between the three skills.

Comment: OMG, it helped so much THX ;)  reaaly thx

Comment: By anonymous "Choosing Attack, Strength & Defence does not increase the xp you gain, it just splits it between the three skills."

Answer (score 0):

After RuneScape 3 update, click on the three bluish orbs icon, then choose whichever kind of exp you want.